# Java Stream equivalent of ReactiveX Observable#scan

Tags: java, list, rx-java, java-stream

ReactiveX has this Very Neat operator called [Scan](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html), which is like reduce, except it emits each intermediate accumulator.

How would I accomplish this with Java Streams? `Stream#reduce` is not what I want because it returns `T`:

```
T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
```

And what I want is to return `Stream<T>`, with each item of the stream being the `T` that was returned on each invocation of the `accumulator`:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
    .myScan(0, (accumulator, i) -> accumulator + i)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // [1, 3, 6]
```

I could do something lame like reducing a `List`, then convert back to a `Stream`, but that's ugly.

Comment: If you don't have to stick to `Stream`, IxJava has this operator: https://github.com/akarnokd/ixjava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/ix/Ix.java#L1924

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream does not support this operation.  You could convert it to an iterator, do it there, and convert back to streams, but there is nothing built-in for streams to do this.

Comment: So in my example, would end up looking something like this `myScan(Stream.of(1, 2, 3), 0, (a, i) -> a + i).collect(Collectors.toList())`?

Comment: Since we couldn't add anything to the Stream interface (like you could in e.g. kotlin)?

Comment: You could write something like that, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Try [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex). I think it provides the extract API you want:

```
List<Integer> result = StreamEx.of(1, 2, 3).scanLeft((i, j) -> i + j);
System.out.println(result); // [1, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to benefit from otherwise discouraged [side-effects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). Since your goal is to process the stream and keeping going on with a stream, we can achieve this using the `map` method. The following code does it utilizing a side-effect.

```
public class Scan {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Accumulator accumulator = new Accumulator();

    Stream<Integer> originalStream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
    Stream<Integer> scannedStream = originalStream
      .map(i -> accumulator.accumulate(i));
    List<Integer> list = scannedStream
      .collect(Collectors.toList()); // [1, 3, 6]

    for (Integer i : list) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }

  private static class Accumulator {

    private int value;

    public int accumulate(int i) {
      return value += i;
    }

  }
}
```

The `Accumulator` can be replaced by a `Function` to be used for different *scan*-operations.

But you have to be aware of the restrictions and concerns (e.g. thread-safty).

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem of [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) is that is overrated and understood as a magic-bullet solution for everything slightly related to any of Collection.

This API has been build for the supporting sequential processing of the elements. There doesn't exist any Stream-alike method performing the snippet below. Moreover, this API is not easily extendable.

Here is what you are speaking about:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).reduce(0, (t, u) -> {
    final Integer s = t + u;
    list.add(s);
    return s;
});

System.out.println(list);   // prints [1, 3, 6]
```

And here is a workaround using [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) which allows you to continue the streaming after performing the `map(..)`:

```
AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);
List<Integer> list = Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
    .map(i -> sum.addAndGet(i))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); 

System.out.println(list);  // prints [1, 3, 6]
```

Sometimes you have to use different way.