# Using Stream operations, map a List<Integer> to a Cumulative Sum List<Integer>

Tags: java, java-stream

I would like to map a List to a List that is the cumulative sum list of the original.

What I mean by this is that the value at each index in the resulting list should be the sum of the values at each index from the beginning up to that point in the original list.

More formally:
[image]
The goal is to achieve this using operations on the Stream of the elements in the original list.

`L = O.stream() [... stuff here ...] .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: how would you write it _without_ streams? replace that `for loop` with `IntStream.range(...)`

Comment: @Eugene You mean stream the indexes?

Comment: @Scratte exactly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936854/java-stream-equivalent-of-reactivex-observablescan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In functional languages, the operation you're trying to perform is called a [Scan](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl). Of course you can implement something similar in Java, but Streams are designed to be parallelizable, so operations like Scan which imply a single-threaded operation aren't well-supported.

```
public static void demo() {
    List<Integer> ints = List.of(1,1,2,1,3);
    List<Integer> sums = ints.stream().collect(scan(Integer::sum));
    System.out.println(sums);
}

public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> scan(BinaryOperator<T> reducer) {
    return Collector.of(
            ArrayList::new,
            (List<T> list, T x) -> {
                if (list.isEmpty()) {
                    list.add(x);
                } else {
                    list.add(reducer.apply(list.get(list.size() - 1), x));
                }
            },
            (l1, l2) -> {throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Scans cannot be efficiently parallelized");}
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be used also:

```
List<Integer> lst = Arrays.asList(1,1,2,1,3);
List<Integer> updList = IntStream.range(0, lst.size()).map((i)-> {
    List<Integer> aux = lst.subList(0, i+1);
    int out=aux.stream().reduce(0,Integer::sum);    
    return out;
}).boxed()
.collect(Collectors.toList());
    
System.out.println(updList.stream().map(i->String.valueOf(i)).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Output

```
1,2,4,5,8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it by stream API, you can do it like that:

```
    int[] accum = new int[1];
    System.out.println(
            Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 1, 3).stream()
                    .map(s -> s + accum[0])
                    .peek(s-> accum[0] = s)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Streams but I don't think we should be using Streams for everything, just for the sake of it. Here there is no clean way to do it without an external list or something.
I don't like to use for loops if I can avoid them so here, I would use a recursive method:

```
private static List<Integer> sum(List<Integer> remainingList, List<Integer> resultList) {
    if(remainingList.isEmpty()) {
        return resultList;
    }

    int currentValue = remainingList.get(0);
    int previousSum = resultList.isEmpty() ? 0 : resultList.get(resultList.size()-1);

    resultList.add(currentValue + previousSum);

    return sum(remainingList.subList(1, remainingList.size()), resultList);
}
```

then

```
List<Integer> resultList = sum(list, new ArrayList<>());
```